# Excel String contains string instead of string equals string

Tags: vba, excel

Hi my code currently looks like this

```
Sub Solbjerg()

Set i = Sheets("Samlet")
Set e = Sheets("ABC")
Dim d
Dim j
d = 7
j = 7

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))

If i.Range("A" & j) = "Cinema ABC" Then
d = d + 1
e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value

End If
j = j + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

However sometimes the data i get is not always "Cinema ABC" but just "ABC". So i need my code to search if the data contains "ABC" instead of equals to "Cinema ABC".
Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
If i.Range("A" & j) = "Cinema ABC" Then
```

to

```
If InStr(1, i.Range("A" & j), "ABC") Then
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Solbjerg()

    Set i = Sheets("Samlet")
    Set e = Sheets("ABC")
    Dim d
    Dim j
    d = 7
    j = 7

    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))

    If i.Range("A" & j) like "*ABC" Then
    d = d + 1
    e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value

    End If
    j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Like, and * works as wildcards